# Wordpress Conditional Tag "If empty"

Tags: php, wordpress, conditional-statements

Need a bit of help if possible:

I have a custom field in my wordpress site, that if it is empty, to not display the div it is inputted into.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<?php
    $newsquote = $cfs->get('news_story_quote');

    if ( ! empty ( $newsquote ) )
    {
    ?>
    <div class="news-story-quote">

    <p><?php global $cfs; echo $cfs->get('news_story_quote'); ?></p>

    </div><!-- News Story Quote -->
    <?php   }   ?>
```

The way to call in the custom field is this : `<?php global $cfs; echo $cfs->get('news_story_quote'); ?>`

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You know, there is a SE for Wordpress: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yea I tried there. No one seems to answer :-(

Comment: Good luck here then, but have you tried a bounty?

Comment: I cannot get it. What the problem is?

Comment: I'm trying to hide the div with the class of news-story-quote if the custom field 'news_story_quote' is empty

Comment: Can't try a bounty for 2 days apparently

Comment: what is in $newsquote? use var_dump http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

Comment: Do you get any error message? Or what does the code (not) do?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you dont use [the function](http://uproot.us/custom-field-suite/docs/get/) inside a loop.

```
$newsquote = $cfs->get('news_story_quote', $post_id);

if ($newsquote) : ?>

    <div class="news-story-quote">

    <p><?php echo $newsquote ?></p>

    </div><!-- News Story Quote -->

<?php endif ?>
```